# To diagnose osteomyelitis of vertebral column in chronic kidney failure

Tags: pathophysiology, kidney

Assume you suspect amyloidosis because of the history of the patient: problem with vertebral column and "purulent" (serous, fibrous, or hemorrhagic) inflammation when patient very young.
Now, the patient has a chronic renal failure.

**Is there any other method to diagnose the fracture of some bone than röntgen?**
Assume you do not know where the fracture is exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Osteomyelitis can be diagnosed with the following imaging techniques <sup>[1]</sup>:

- first of all: **radiography** to view the anatomy of the bone
- the sonography can be used to diagnose fluid collections, periosteal involvement. It is also the most useful procedure for kidney assessment <sup>[2]</sup>.
- CT is also useful to detect early osseous erosion, but is less sensitive when it comes to bone infection
- **MRI** is the most sensitive and specific for osteomyelitis
- Nuclear imaging can be used to identify multifocal osseous involvement.

References:

1. Carlos Pineda *et al.*, [*Radiographic Imaging in Osteomyelitis: The Role of Plain Radiography, Computed Tomography, Ultrasonography, Magnetic Resonance Imaging, and Scintigraphy*](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2884903/)
2. American College of Radiology, [*Renal failure*](http://www.acr.org/~/media/cfbe883c503c45e982d4b722de80230b.pdf)

Comment: Is there any techninques in Propedeutics to limit the area of the research. Assume you have no idea where the fracture is, not about side and how big fracture is.

Comment: You can look for the basic signs and symptoms of fracture http://www.webmd.com/a-to-z-guides/understanding-fractures-symptoms